# Rotate a button in visual studio 2013 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, hover, windows-store-apps

I've created a Windows Store Application in visual studio 2013, and I really don't know how to rotate a button on PointerEntered in c#. Using hover, I just want to rotate it to 360 angle. I would appreciate it if somebody will help me.

Comment: Ehm... if you rotate it 360 degrees, you haven't actually rotated it at all. Do you mean an animation?

Comment: are you after an animated rotation?

Comment: Ok, fine 135 degrees,I don't know, x degrees ∈ [1,359].

Comment: Lots of samples if you can use jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/Anatol/T6kDR/

Comment: Yeah, I want an animation like those, but using c#.

Comment: Isn't there a transform rotation property on XAML elements? It's been a while since I used XAML, but I thought there was.

Comment: Yes, it is , but I want to rotate it on PointerEntered, to do a little animation. If I use xaml, the button stay rotated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx):

The XAML:

```
<Canvas Height="200" Width="200">

  <!-- Rotates the Polyline 45 degrees about the point (0,0). -->
  <Polyline Points="25,25 0,50 25,75 50,50 25,25 25,0" 
    Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10"
    Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="50">
    <Polyline.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="45" />
    </Polyline.RenderTransform>
  </Polyline>
</Canvas>
```

The c# Code:
(Use this as and where required...)

```
// Create a Polyline.
Polyline polyline1 = new Polyline();
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 25));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(0, 50));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 75));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(50, 50));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 25));
polyline1.Points.Add(new Point(25, 0));
polyline1.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
polyline1.StrokeThickness = 10;

// Create a RotateTransform to rotate 
// the Polyline 45 degrees about its 
// top-left corner.
RotateTransform rotateTransform1 =
    new RotateTransform(45);
polyline1.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1;

// Create a Canvas to contain the Polyline.
Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
canvas1.Width = 200;
canvas1.Height = 200;
Canvas.SetLeft(polyline1, 75);
Canvas.SetTop(polyline1, 50);
canvas1.Children.Add(polyline1);
```